# Can I generate exe from ubuntu

Tags: c++, exe

I'm using Ubuntu and I use Code::Blocks as my IDE, I'm still a student and my professor wants us to write and compile some c++ programs and give him the exes to check them

**Is there a way for me to generate exe files on my Linux os ?**

ps: I'm new to Linux so take it easy on me.

**Thanks**

Comment: Learn about cross-compiling.  The tools exist in Ubuntu too.

Comment: If you build your C++ code, you'll get a binary that can run on _similar_ systems (like other people who use the same version of Ubuntu). If you mean you want to build an `.exe` like for Windows, you'll have to cross-compile or build your code in Windows. A first thing to look at would be the [`mingw64-w64` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mingw-w64) in Ubuntu.

Comment: googling "cross compile from linux to windows" yielded many interesting results.

Comment: You [need a cross-compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/897303)
You can use mingw tool chain, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2034007/1566267) for instructions.

Comment: Note only: actually linux can run .exe files. (I'm not sure if linux c++ compilers build exe files, but for instance I compiled a lot of pascal programs on Ubuntu, and it gave me exe, but this was long time ago)

Comment: @Lasoloz No, a) they doesn't build exe files without cross-compilation b) you probably successfully run exe under linux because it had automatically started under some emulator-app like wine.

Comment: With Wine you don't even need "cross-compilation" (a compiler aware of running on a different platform than it is compiling for).  You can install a Windows compiler (with supporting files and tools) on Linux and run it under Wine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto compile for Windows on Linux with gcc / g++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/howto-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)

Answer (score 4):

You [need a cross-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897303). You can use mingw tool chain, if your want 32bit Windows application, install mingw32. [Here are the detailed instructions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_and_Cross_Compilers) for using it with IDE CodeBlocks.

If you want to build 64-bit applications, try [mingw-w64 fork](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

Also, then you could run the compiled application (or, even some native windows applications, compiled on Windows) in Linux under Wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wine myapp.exe
```